# Overriding readData in QIODevice subclass returns incorrect result

Tags: c++, python, qt, inheritance, pyside

I am trying to subclass QFile in PySide to implement custom read behavior. However, as seen in the simplified code below, even if the subclass' readData implementation just calls the parent's readData function, the returned data is incorrect. Subclassing other QIODevices such as QBuffer also causes incorrect return values. Has anyone successfully subclassed a QIODevice?

```
from PySide import QtCore

class FileChild1(QtCore.QFile):
    pass

class FileChild2(QtCore.QFile):
    def readData(self, maxlen):
        return super(FileChild2, self).readData(maxlen)


f1 = FileChild1('test.txt')
f1.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadWrite|QtCore.QIODevice.Truncate)
f1.write('Test text for testing')
f1.seek(0)
print 'FileChild1: ', repr(f1.read(50))

f2 = FileChild2('test2.txt')
f2.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadWrite|QtCore.QIODevice.Truncate)
f2.write('Test text for testing')
f2.seek(0)
print 'FileChild2: ', repr(f2.read(50))

>>> FileChild1:  PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('Test text for testing')
>>> FileChild2:  PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('─ Q ►│A☻ @  p¼a☻Test text for testing\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
```

Comment: In the original C++ version of Qt, readData has the following signature `qint64 QIODevice::readData ( char * data, qint64 maxSize )`, where the data is read into a char array and the length is returned. In PySide and PyQt, the read data is returned directly in a string. Could this discrepancy have something to do with it?

Comment: This works as expected in PyQt4 (PyQt4: 4.8.6, Qt: 4.7.4). Maybe a bug in PySide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your script with PyQt 4.8 and PyQt 4.9 with Python 2.7.2 / Qt 4.8.0, and in both cases it produces the following output:

```
FileChild1:  'Test text for testing'
FileChild2:  'Test text for testing'
```

So `readData` returns a byte string, as per the [PyQt4 docs](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qfile.html#readData).

Using PySide 1.0.9 with Python 2.7.2 / Qt 4.8.0, I get this output:

```
FileChild1:  PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('Test text for testing')
FileChild2:  PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('')
```

Not sure why there is a difference in return type between PyQt4 and PySide, but there is clearly some kind of bug in PySide.

There is a bug report [here](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-bz-archive/994.html) which looks like it may be somewhat related, but it's not particularly recent (PySide 1.0.7).

Comment: It's really too bad that this bug exists, I'd rather use PySide, but it looks like I don't have a choice.

Answer (score 1):

The bug of PySide is from shiboken, that: qint64 is used in QIODevice as offset type, but qint64 is mapped to "int" in Python 2.x, not "long". When the value of qint64 is larger than qint32, reading that value will cause Python 2.x to throw OverflowError. 
Similar OverflowError happens when using qint64 as Slot/Signal/Property or whatever Qt meta types to communicate Qt C++ code with Python.

I am also looking for solution to bypass this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Very valid on Qt5 and PySide2 as well. We are investigating.